# Data encryption software

Tags: cross-platform, encryption

We are in need of a software capable of encrypting data with AES-256 to store it in the cloud.

The problem is that I need a solution to work on Windows, Linux and OS X.
Previously for Windows we have used 7zip, but it has no official support for Linux or OS X.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe use 3 simple encryption/decryption command lines for each OS? This seems too trivial to make a cross-platform app for.

Comment: Some users are not used to use a cli.

Comment: What's wrong with unofficial p7zip packages?

Comment: We are looking for something with official support; maybe even a commercial software.

Comment: Many p7zip packages have official support, from their respective communities, e.g. http://forum.kekaosx.com/ (but yes I see your point to have the same software on all platforms)

Comment: True, but they fail in some ways: for example we created an archive on Ubuntu, but 7zip fails to decrypt the data so p7zip is not a solution as I said. Maybe they are good for something, but this is not the case.

Comment: I'm not very knowledgeable in the topic of encryption, but how hard can it be to create a GUI wrapper application that executes command lines under the hood? Maybe you can ditch the encryption software package bits and just encrypt to raw data?

Comment: Are you sure you understood the question? As said above, using it on different systems will cause the use of different libraries which encrypt data a bit differently. As state previously, an archive created on Ubuntu fails to be decrypted on Windows even tho we used 7zip and p7zip.

Comment: 7zip archives are compatible between all platforms. If you created an archive on Ubuntu and it failed to decrypt on Windows, then you made a mistake somewhere: corrupt copy or wrong password or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say [truecrypt](http://truecrypt.sourceforge.net/), it supports [Linux, OS x,](http://truecrypt.sourceforge.net/OtherPlatforms.html) and windows and it supports [AES-256](https://superuser.com/questions/207831/which-truecrypt-algorithm-is-the-safest) encryption. All your requirements. I think it is safe to say that Truecrypt is the most widely used and among the most trusted encryption software out there, and it is free and open source.

Comment: @Sandel don't worry everybody uses it, if I was the creator of truecrypt I'd do the same thing, because people should know that nothing is completely safe. see this http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29375/is-7-zips-aes-encryption-just-as-secure-as-truecrypts-version